# Heroku : Mcrypt PHP extension required (php7 on Ubuntu16)

Tags: php, heroku, laravel-4, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to push my code on the heroku app. Usually it always worked, but today it returned me the following error :

```
php artisan clear-compiled
remote: Mcrypt PHP extension required.
remote: Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error

remote: [RuntimeException]

remote: Error Output:

remote: install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] []...

remote: ! Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
remote: ! Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: ! Push rejected to dev-forde-hr.
```

So I tried to install mcrypt for php7.0 but it returned me that everything was already installed.

I'm using php7 on Ubuntu 16 and it's a Laravel 4 web app.

I don't know what to do more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue by adding this to composer.json :

```
"ext-mcrypt": "*"
```

and composer update afterwards